# How can i center a div and fill it with other divs so that it fits all the resolutions?

Tags: tags, html, centering

I have been creating my website on a 1280*800 resolution computer and it works just fine until I use another computer with a different resolution. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
#IDdiv {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:80%; //for example
height:80%; //for example
}
```

It will look similar on all resolutions.
This will center the div horizontally.

Comment: Now, I have other divs under the main div. How do i make those divs  to be related to the main div that i called wrapper?